# Prove for $ar^k = r^{-k}a$ all integers $k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Please help. I am working with the symmetries of a square.

> Prove $ar^k = r^{-k}a$ for all integers $k$.

Attempt: Base case: $P(1)$ is true since $ar = r^{-1}a$.

Let $P(k)$ be the statement $ar^k = r^{-k}a$ for which is true, where $k$ is an integer. Then $P(k)$ must imply $P(k+1)$.

Thus, $ar^{k+1} = r^{-(k+1)}a$

Can anyone help me

Thank you

Comment: What are $r$ and $a$ supposed to be? (Because if they're intended to be real numbers, then the statement is clearly false. Perhaps you are working in a dihedral group?)

Comment: Yes, I am working with the symmetries of a square. But I am not sure what to do. r is a rotation, and a is a flip.

Answer (score 1):

$ar=r^{-1}a$.

$ara^{-1}=r^{-1}$.

$(ara^{-1})^k=r^{-k}$.

But $(ara^{-1})^k=ara^{-1}ara^{-1}ara^{-1}\dots ara^{-1}ara^{-1}ara^{-1}=ar^ka^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking it up
$$ar^{k+1} = (ar)r^{k} = ... (\text{ other work here }) ... = r^{-1}(r^{-k}a) = r^{-k-1}a$$